# How to print out nodes in my code?

Tags: java, linked-list

I can't figure out a way to print out all of the nodes based on my code. How do i go about printing them all out based on the current code

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;

public class Linkedlist
{
    static public class Node
    {
        Node next;
        String data;
    }
    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in));
        Node head = null;
        Node node = new Node();
        while(true)
        {
            String str = stdin.readLine();
            if (!str.equals("fin"))
            {
                node.data = str;
                node.next = head;
                head = node;
                node = new Node();
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You've shown the code to *create* the linked list, but not to iterate through the list. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Are you asking how to call `System.out.println(node.data)`? Or are you having some other problem?

Comment: it is the barebones implementation my teacher handed out

Comment: i think i misunderstood you, i wrote the above code myself based on a very simple thing the teacher showed us

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep a reference to your head node.  Right now you just re-set it every time you add a new item.  Then you can do something like this:

```
Node current = head;
while (current != null) {
  System.out.println(current.data);
  current = current.next;
}
```